# Ocaml use let rec in the let rec

Tags: ocaml

```
let k = 2
let n = 4
let rec f i =
  if i >= n then ()
  else (
    let rec q k =
      if 1 = 1 then ()
      else ();;
  );;
f 1;;
```

When I try to compile, there is error:  File "OCaml.ml", line 8, characters 13-15: Error: Syntax error: operator expected.

How can I use *let rec* function in the *else of let rec* function?

Comment: I think your problem can be reduced to `(() ;; ())`.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll not spoil the fun of writing the full function but answer "*How can I use let rec function in the else of let rec function?*":

You are missing the `in` statement:

```
let k = 2
let n = 4
let rec f i =
  if i >= n then ()
  else
    let rec q k =
      if 1 = 1 then ()
      else ()
    in
    f 1
```

The general pattern for local declarations is:

`let identifier = term in expr`

In case you need to write mutually recursive functions, you need the `and` keyword, e.g.:

```
let rec f x = g x and g x = f x in "test";;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat ugly solution which will hopefully not please your teacher, but which can be useful nonetheless to get you started. You would need to get rid of the `for` loop, find better names for the variables and think about return values.

The `comb` function returns nothing (`unit`) and accepts parameters `k`, `n` and `cb`, the latter being a callback function of type `(int list -> unit)` which is called for each combination that is generated:

```
let comb k n cb =
  let rec level z seen m = 
    if (z = 0) 
    then (cb seen) 
    else for i = m to n 
         do
           level (z - 1) (i::seen) (i + 1)
         done
   in level k [] 1;;
```

Notice how `let rec` is used to define a recursive `level` function which is bound and can be called from both `<definition>` and `<expression>`:

```
let rec level <arguments> = <definition> in <expression>
```

A possible callback function is one which prints results:

```
comb 2 4 (fun x -> 
           List.iter 
             (fun c -> print_int c ; print_string " ") 
             (List.rev x) ; 
           print_newline ());;
```

Output:

```
1 2                                                                                 
1 3                                                                                 
1 4                                                                                 
2 3 
2 4 
3 4
- : unit = ()
```